# Visual Studio created DLL not recognized by Win7 32

Tags: visual-studio, dll, windows-10, windows-7

My customer provided a new version of a DLL that I used a few years ago to create my project. I am assuming they used a newer version of Visual Studio (than before). My C compiler (LABWindwos/CVI) did not recognize the supplied .lib file and refused to link my project. When I try to inspect the provided DLL I am getting an error. Dependency Walker tells me it is not a valid DLL. There's also a difference when I inspect this file using Properties right click mouse menu. It does not decode the version, copyright info or anything that it would normally do for a DLL. This is for Win7 32. When I try the same operation on Win10 64 it works as expected. I see copyright info, version etc. Dependency walker also works properly displaying all dependencies and providing names for exported functions.
When I try to inspect this file using Dependencies(x86) I am getting an error: Invalid PE-COFF.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
DM

Tried on Win7 32 and Win10 64 machines

Comment: The best way to diagnose this would be with the ``dumpbin`` utility where you can use ``/headers`` to see the DLL PE header information. See [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference).

Comment: Note that the DEFAULT build settings for a Win32 DLL built for x86 even with VS 2022 (17.5.4) is set to be compatible all the way back to Windows Vista. The real limitation is that Windows 7 SP1 is the oldest OS that you can install the Visual C/C++ Runtime REDIST. You can use ``dumpbin /imports`` to see what dependent DLLs and entry-points it's looking for.